# Alter main menu button text and URL path depending on OG Role

Tags: 7, hooks, organic-groups, navigation

I know you can change menu links depending on drupal based roles (authenticated, non authenticated...) and by using Rules module also.

I am using Organic Group roles and I am having difficulties in showing different links on the menu bar depending whether my site's user IS or ISN'T a member of a group.

When he/she signs up a 'join' button is on the nav bar --> after joining a group he can now write content so the 'add' button replaces the join button on the nav bar with the appropriate URL paths.

Can a hook be used to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the `access callback` of the items array in [hook_menu_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7). The implementation of the [user menu](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_menu/7) gives a good example.
To make it work with Organic groups, you could declare an access callback function using [og_is_member](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!og!og.module/function/og_is_member/7) or [og_user_access](http://og_user_access):

```
function MY_MODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['MY/PATH'] = array(
    'access callback' => 'MY_MODULE_custom_menu_access_callback',
    // Assuming your group is a node and the menu appears on the nodes
    // page (/node/[nid]), then array(1) would pass the node ID to your
    // function, which in this case acts as a group ID.
    'access arguments' => array(1),
    // etc...
  );
    return $items;
}
function MY_MODULE_custom_menu_access_callback($gid) {
  return og_is_member('node', $gid);
}
```

Where `MY/PATH` would be the path to the entity type representing the group. If you are using a node as a group, this would be `node/%`. As `'access arguments'` we use the [arg function](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/arg/7). `0` would be `node` and `1` would be the node ID of the node.

Comment: My group is created from a 'create group' content type. My questions are: 1. under 'title' what do I put? -> I want to use this hook on the default menu so do I just put 'Main Menu'? 2. What goes under 'MY/PATH'? 3. Under 'access arguments' array do I add the URL of the menu items I want to change? This is my very first hook so a more detailed explanation would be much appreciated! EDIT: Just to let you know I have created a module and added a .info and a .module file that will contain this hook

Comment: @qaz123 Updated the answer.

Comment: UPDATE: I have just realised  I have got [node:content-type]/[node:title] in my Pathauto Settings so no gid is present in the URL so that's why it might not work...

Comment: @qaz123 Should work with path alias as well, as Drupal knows the internals path. So if it's a node, use `node/%`, it does not matter if you have an alias.

Comment: Sorry for this bit I'm not good at programming and I'm finding this hard... This is what I understand:  The menu alter function looks at items in my url path - to do this it calls the result from menu access callback function to get the group id from the node url.  Under access arguments do I have to list the arguments/ what to run the user is part of a group  (TRUE: show the add content button) and if the user hasnt created a group (FALSE show add group button) Is this correct? (Is my case similar to this: http://tinyurl.com/zylyckc)